# How do I capture all images from camera with android app running in background?

Tags: android, android-camera

I know how to make a preview and capture images inside an app.

However, I want to make a "capture mode". In this mode, the user may close my app and any pictures that get taken in other apps such as the default camera app get sent to my app, so I can make a gallery of them in my app.

I have an app which has a button that switches capture mode on and off, but how do I make it listen to camera events happening elsewhere? Would I have to search through the gallery for pictures taken in the time frame that capture mode was on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html to find images located on the phone's internal or external storage during a specific time frame.

If you are doing any sort of work on these images, you could also investigate [using a Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to ensure that your app can process the images while the other apps are running, but this hopefully won't be necessary.